# Reduce code duplication in class template specialization (array<Unique_ptr>)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, template-classes

How to reduce code duplication of a class that is template specialized?

I am trying to create a class (`MyArray`) that acts like `std::vector` but receives raw-pointer as parameter in some functions.

Here is a simplified version of it :-

```
template<class T> class MyArray{
    T database[10];
    public: T& get(int index){return database[index];}
    void set(int index, T t){
        database[index]=t;
    }
};
template<class T> class MyArray<std::unique_ptr<T>>{
    T* database[10];
    public: T*& get(int index){return database[index];}
    void set(int index, std::unique_ptr<T> t){
        T* tmp=t.release();
        database[index]=tmp;  
    }
};
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/u4CT7t) is a test:-

```
class B{};
int main() {
    MyArray<B>   test1;
    MyArray<B*>  test2;
    MyArray<std::unique_ptr<B>> test3;
    test3.set(2,std::make_unique<B>()));
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**  Please demonstrate an elegant way to reduce the above code duplication in `MyArray`.

A solution that I wished for may look like :-

```
template<class T> class MyArray{
    using U = if(T=std::uniquePtr<X>){X*}else{T};
    U database[10];
    public: U& get(int index){return database[index];}
    void set(int index, T t){
        U u = convert(t);//<-- some special function
        database[index]=u;
    }
};
```

There might be some memory leak / corruption.    For simplicity, please overlook it.
 I just want an idea/rough guide. (no need to provide a full run-able code, but I don't mind)

In real life, there are 20+ function in `MyArray` and I wish to do the same refactoring for many classes.

**Edit:** I have (minor) edited some code and tag.  Thank AndyG and Jarod42.

Comment: This code is not C++11... `std::make_unique` is a C++14 feature. Perhaps you're using a version of Visual Studio, 2013?

Comment: The `move` in `std::move(std::make_unique` is unneeded.

Comment: @AndyG Acclamation!  I will edit it asap.  Thank.

Comment: @Jarod42  Thank.  That is new knowledge for me.  I have just noticed that my code also contained other errors.  I will try to fix some of them.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe can you delegate the implementation details to a struct you provide to your class, and you specialize this struct, not MyArray:

```
template <typename T>
struct Policy {
  using type = T;
  static type convert(T t) { ... }
};

template <typename T>
struct Policy<std::unique_ptr<T>> {
  using type = T*;
  static type convert(T t) { ... }
};

template <typename T, typename P = Policy<T>>
class MyArray
{
  using type = typename P::type;

  void set(int index, T t) { type result = P::convert(t); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You might think about using a common base class for the common functionality:

```
template<class T>
class Base{
    protected:
    T database[10];
    public:
    T& get(int index){return database[index];} 
};

template<class T> 
class MyArray : public Base<T>{
    public:
    void set(int index, T t){
        this->database[index]=t;
    }
};

template<class T> 
class MyArray<std::unique_ptr<T>> : public Base<T*>
{
    public:
    void set(int index, std::unique_ptr<T>&& t){
        T* tmp=t.release();
        this->database[index]=tmp;   //a little different
    }
};
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gbmSSImZTQUKFBaV)

Comment: It is funny that I just notices you change the font size of "Demo".  XD